# JavaFx: Switching scenes (Parent issue)

Tags: javafx

Today I came across some issue, maybe you could explain me why it has to be written that way.

```
Parent parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxmlFiles/MainScreen.fxml"));
Scene MainScene = new Scene(parent);
Stage stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
stage.setScene(MainScene);
stage.show();
```

I want to ask you about the 3rd line of this code (switching scenes).
Why is it cast to `Stage` first and then to `Node`?

Why can't we just write it following way:

```
Parent parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxmlFiles/MainScreen.fxml"));
Scene MainScene = new Scene(parent);
Stage stage = new Stage(scene);
stage.setScene(MainScene);
stage.show();
```

`Parent` is just kind of a layout provided by FXML files, right?
If not please explain me what it is exacly :P

Comment: I'd have to see when that event is being called, but that's a pretty overly complex way to switch a scene.  If you're keeping the same stage then you just need to switch the scene on the stage.  If you want a new stage then go with the second method you showed.

Answer (score 1):

> Why it have to be casted firstly by Stage and then to the Node Object?

That's not what's happening. Look at the parentheses. You are calling `event.getSource()` and casting the result of that to a `Node`. You are then calling `getScene()` on that `Node`, `getWindow()` on the resulting `Scene`, and casting that `Window` to a `Stage`.

The code is equivalent to:

```
Object source = event.getSource();
Node node = (Node) source ;
Scene scene = node.getScene();
Window window = scene.getWindow();
Stage stage = (Stage) window ;
```

> Why can't we just write it fllowing way:

```
Parent parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxmlFiles/MainScreen.fxml"));
Scene MainScene = new Scene(parent);
Stage stage = new Stage(scene);
stage.setScene(MainScene);
stage.show();
```

That does something different; it creates a new `Stage` instead of setting the scene on the existing stage. Use the code that matches the actual functionality you want.

Comment: Okey, i understand. So what type of data we will get if we are using event.getSource() function? Why we are forced to use casting?

Comment: Read the [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html?is-external=true#getSource--). `getSource` returns an `Object`; i.e. the source can be any object.

Comment: Okey, now i'm confused ;P. "Nodes are presentation objects. They have actions, properties and localized display names - they are the place where the architecture meets the human. Nodes typically wrap some model object and provide human-readable names, icons, etc." So if nodes are, truly speaking, also Objects, why we have to cast Object to an Object :(. I don't understand.

Comment: You're not casting it to an object. You're casting it to a `Node`. I think you need to review some introductory Java material on casting.